# Fetch all Facebook comments within certain time frame

Tags: facebook-graph-api, restfb

I am using [restfb](http://restfb.com) and searching for a way to fetch all comments from my fan Page(all the comments on my Page since yesterday even comments to the post that are posted before yesterday), I am able to fetch all the comments from my post that i posted since yesterday but not the comments from the post that are posted before yesterday.

```
Date yesterday = new Date(currentTimeMillis() - 1000L * 60L * 60L * 24L);
Connection<Post> post = fbclient.fetchConnection("page", Post.class,
            Parameter.with("until", currentTimeMillis()), Parameter.with("since", yesterday));

List<Post> pagePost = post.getData();
Post.Comments comments
List<Comment> commentList;

for (int i = 0; i < pagePost.size(); i++) {
        Post post = pagePost.get(i);
        Date createdTime = post.getCreatedTime();
        Date updatedTime = post.getUpdatedTime();

out.println("Post since: " + yesterday +" "+ post.getMessage() + " Created time: " + createdTime +" Updated time: "+ updateTime);

comments = post.getComments();
        if(comments!=null) {
            commentList = comments.getData();
if(!commentList.isEmpty())
                for (int k = 0; k < commentList.size(); k++) {
                    String message = commentList.get(k).getMessage();
                    Date messageTime = commentList.get(k).getCreatedTime();
                    String userName = commentList.get(k).getFrom().getName();

                    out.println("Comment : " + "\"" + message + "\"" + " From: " + userName +"    at: " +messageTime);

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Short*: This is not possible.

*Long*: Facebook uses the since and unit parameter only on the **creation date** of a Post. If you fetch all Post from "yesterday", you get only the Posts **created** yesterday. The ones that are **updated** yesterday are ignored. This is a major issue but Facebook don't want to change this.

With a Graph API 2.0 Application you may use some FQL magic - but there's some bug, the updated time is not updated correctly (https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/337535839676314/).

The official approach is to use Realtime Updates.